# How do I properly construct a graph from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand that an adjacency matrix shows connectivity between vertices but I don't get how to properly construct the graph from them. In one of my lectures I was given this adjacency matrix:

[image]

From it I constructed a graph that pretty much resembled this solution provided:

[image]

The difference is however that I didn't put my line from 4,5 on a slant like that and my 1, 2, 3 structure was angled differently. Does it matter about the angle or rotation of the shape and lines themselves? My solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "angle or rotation" doesn't matter at all; your answer is fine. It's entirely a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

Given the edges between vertices, its not possible to find the angle of rotation of edges. Also you need a space to measure the angles. So in your case any orientation of graph should work.

Comment: Note that orientation in graph theory refers to direction of the edges. I know you did not mean it in that context, but I wanted to clarify. :-)